# Star like moving object in the sky

Tags: star

Today morning, around 4 am, I saw a star like object moving from right to left with a speed faster than airplane and then it started moving from left to right and then vanished in the sky. After few minutes it again started moving from the same place it vanished, in forward direction and then again vanished, then again I saw it moving in same direction but from different direction where it vanished earlier.
I wonder what it was? It couldn't be a airplane for sure. Aeroplane doesn't fly that high and doesn't look like a star.

Location- Sydney, Australia
Date - morning 30th October 2021

Answer (score 3):

It is incredibly difficult to just look at a point source object from the ground with your eyes to know how high it is flying. A larger object several miles in the sky and a drone several hundred feet will look identical; just point sources of light. In situations like these in this day and age, it often ends up being a drone, and this is reinforced by the fact that it is moving quickly and erratically.

Comment: This. Humans can only directly perceive depth (by stereo vision) within about 10 meters, beyond that we rely on visual cues like neighboring objects and our own motion through the environment. When you're standing still and looking at the sky, you lose these cues as well, and there's very little to judge distance by. It could be a drone, or even something like an insect or bat flying through a light.